# Changing the colour of a button

Tags: html, css, button, colors

I'm having problems in order to change the colour of this button. This is the code:

```
<div class = "Petrol">
   <a href="PayMethod.php"><button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button"><span class="Text">Petrol<br><small>(Hi-Grade)</small></span></button>
   </a>
</div>
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Why do you need a button tag when you have an a tag? It's kind of redundant.

Comment: `btn` is for the shape of the `button` and `btn-default` is for the coloring.

Answer (score 4):

if you need to change the color of the button do this:

```
 .btn {
      background-color:blue;
    }
```

if you need to change the text inside the color of the button

```
.btn {
      color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming by the classes you used, I think you are using Bootstrap. Bootstrap provide pre-defined classes to change bg color of buttons. Replace `btn-default` by any of the following to get a different color. `btn-primary`, `btn-success`, `btn-info`, `btn-warning`, `btn-danger`, and `btn-link`.
Take a look at the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options).

You could also apply a custom class `btn-custom` and style it.

```
.btn-custom {
  background: #ff0; /* use your color here */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Straightfoward way works fine

```
.btn {
  color:blue;
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/dGYNzp)